# AMP accordion ( menu close on click )

Tags: amp-html

I am using the amp accordion here  https://stargame.ca/amp
Everything is fine except that when the user click on a particular section with the anchor link #game for example, I would like the accordion to close by itself.

Is this possible ?

Thanks

Comment: I think you have 2 out of 3 conditions correct. You have the CSS for #game; the href for #game in the accordion; but no target for #game. I think that when you set the intra-page href target, the menu will close when navigating to the target.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible at the moment. I'd recommend filing a feature request for the amp-accordion component on [Github](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/new). This could be made possible by making the `expanded` attribute a binding target for amp-bind.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `<amp-selector>` and build a dropdown that closes automatically.

I made something similar as a proof of concept, you can modify it as you like

```
    `http://jsbin.com/falohu`
```